# Selenium switchTo return error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have scenario to click hyperlink, and will open new tab (active window will move to new tab after click hyperlink)

When i try to move to webdriver to new tab using `switchTo()` method, then followed by `WebDriverWait.until` browser automatically close with error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from no such execution context
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
```

I use `System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandle())` and i can see driver moving to new tab.

How i can fix above error?
I have try using Iterator for loop into windowHandle

Seems can't use WebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions) to wait for new tab.
Always getting an error `cannot determine loading status from no such execution context`

Weird thing, I can use `Thread.sleep(1000)`.

How i can avoid using Thread.sleep in this case?
Because implicit wait can't work too

**Working code with Thread.sleep()**

```
public class MyCode {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private WebDriverWait wait;

    @Test
    public void openPrestaShopFromDemoWebsite() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions()
                .addArguments("--start-maximized", "--incognito");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.navigate().to("http://demo.prestashop.com");
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("loadingMessage")));

        driver.switchTo().frame("framelive");
        String parentTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Ecommerce software by PrestaShop")).click();

        Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> it = windowHandles.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String newTab = it.next();

            if (!parentTab.equals(newTab)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(newTab);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Create and develop your business with PrestaShop"));
                driver.close();
            }
        }

        driver.switchTo().window(parentTab);
        driver.switchTo().frame("framelive");
        assertThat(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Personal info")).isDisplayed());

        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

**Not working code (cannot determine loading status from no such execution context)**

```
public class MyCode {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private WebDriverWait wait;
    private WebElement element;

    @Test
    public void openPrestaShopFromDemoWebsite() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions()
                .addArguments("--start-maximized", "--incognito");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.navigate().to("http://demo.prestashop.com");
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("loadingMessage")));

        driver.switchTo().frame("framelive");
        String parentTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Ecommerce software by PrestaShop")).click();

        Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> it = windowHandles.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String newTab = it.next();

            if (!parentTab.equals(newTab)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(newTab);

                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Create and develop your business with PrestaShop"));
                driver.close();
            }
        }

        driver.switchTo().window(parentTab);
        driver.switchTo().frame("framelive");
        assertThat(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Personal info")).isDisplayed());

        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Update the question with the code block for _...click hyperlink..._ step

Answer (score 6):

I had been running into this same problem for a few days and it seems that it is actually an issue with chromedriver. The solution that worked for me was to add the following flag/argument to your chromedriver options:

```
--disable-site-isolation-trials
```

[Here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2660&q=switchTo().window) is the chromedriver issue (and solution) I'm referring to.

If the flag does not work, you may also try upgrading to chromedriver v75

Comment: Thank you..
this is did for me.

Comment: Yes!!! That's it!!!

Answer (score -2):

As the link is opening in a new tab, you need to switch the driver to the new tab and for that, you can use the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

And if you want to switch to the original tab, you need to use:

```
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
```

Comment: doesn't work, after switchTo() and followed by WebDriverWait.until, webdriver return `cannot determine loading status from no such execution context`

Comment: @J.Doem Can you add the code which you have used after switching the tab ?